# changing display properties in Android

Tags: android, android-view, presentation

The two display info is,

```
Main Display-> DisplayMetrics{density=1.4375, width=1920, height=1011, scaledDensity=1.4375, xdpi=159.895, ydpi=160.421}

Secondary Display-> DisplayMetrics{density=2.0, width=1920, height=1080, scaledDensity=2.0, xdpi=320.0, ydpi=320.0}
```

is there any method to set the properties the same in the program without rooting?

because the views show different size even if I use dp and sp.

Comment: Do you want to show a view in same size in all the devices?

Comment: @Changer No, one device. But a it's POS has two displays.

Answer (score 0):

Display properties are fixed by the system/framework and cannot be changed by an application.
Your application needs to support the different display metrics.

If you want to different dimensions/layouts for different display sizes, declare alternate layouts and dimensions.

See here how to support different displays :
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: It'd be better if you share some example. And I didn't mean that. And no, you can change the properties. There are a bunch of apps in the Google Play.